# MarshalledContentWrapper error in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

Actually i am trying example on this link
https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/02/21/jbpm5-example-for-forms-with-variables

now when it is calling the ftl file on reaching HUMAN TASK      it is showing this on jsp page

```
Model Number: MarshalledContentWrapper{content=B@1e0d7c5,
marshaller=org.drools.marshalling.impl.SerializablePlaceholderResolverStrategy,
type=class java.lang.String} 
Quantity: MarshalledContentWrapper{content=[B@75ffe5,
marshaller=org.drools.marshalling.impl.SerializablePlaceholderResolverStrategy,         
type=class java.lang.String}
Priority: MarshalledContentWrapper{content=[B@f31cdb,
marshaller=org.drools.marshalling.impl.SerializablePlaceholderResolverStrategy, 
type=class java.lang.String}
```

and then textboxes and submit button.

when I click on submit

I am getting this output on my console.

```
Human Task Started....
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jbpm.task.utils.MarshalledContentWrapper
          at org.jbpm.task.utils.ContentMarshallerHelper.unmarshall(ContentMarshallerHelper.java:157)
          at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler.handleCompletedTask(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:208)
          at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler$1.run(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:187)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

how to resolve this issue does any one have idea on this.

Comment: How are you sending the data inside the task before completing it. Can you please show the code that you are using?

Comment: I have written following code in script task of my BPMN file 

    map = new java.util.HashMap();
    
    map.put("priority","High");
    map.put("modelNumber","1234");
    map.put("quantity","225");

    kcontext.setVariable("map", map);

I am doing example of human task from this link 

https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/02/21/jbpm5-example-for-forms-with-variables

Answer (score 2):

I have written following code in script task of my BPMN file

```
map = new java.util.HashMap();

map.put("priority","High");
map.put("modelNumber","1234");
map.put("quantity","225");

kcontext.setVariable("map", map);
```

I am doing example of human task from this link

https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/02/21/jbpm5-example-for-forms-with-variables